# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+x^{2020})} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+x^{2020})} \, dx$$

At a first glance, I notice that $\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ is the derivative of $\arctan(x)$. Meanwhile, partial fraction will not work in this case (at least from my perspective) because the power of the $x$ in $\frac{1}{1+x^{2020}}$ is too large. Then I tried to approach this problem by integration by part. Then I got the following result:

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+x^{2020})} \, dx= \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{1+x^{2020}}|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty\frac{-2020\tan^{-1}(x)x^{2019}}{(1+x^{2020})^{2}}\,dx
$$

Since $\lim_{x\to \infty}\tan^{-1}(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}1+x^{2020}=\infty$

Then $$\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{1+x^{2020}}|_0^\infty = 0 $$

However, how should I proceed from $$\int_0^\infty\frac{-2020\tan^{-1}(x)x^{2019}}{(1+x^{2020})^{2}}\,dx$$
Please feel free to point out any calculation error if there are some.

Comment: Use the substitution $u=1/x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\to\frac{1}{x}$, take average: $I=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, how do you observe we need to substitute  u = 1/x ? I’m interested.

Comment: @Chad It's experience. : )